# Run time error 13 when column doesn't have different values

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

## Following is part of my program which does the follwoing function

It will look into column K and column L and create tabs according to the combinations. For example if column K has a  cell value "Apple" and column L has one  cell value "Orange" it will create a tab 1) Apple - Orange

The new tab will have all the rows with this combination
So once complete the running of macro , the whole data will get divided to different tabs according to the K - L combination

My problem is it is giving a run time error when entire column K or entire column L has only one value. For example if entire K column has 10 rows and all column k cells has value Apple it will give error. same goes for column L.

```
Dim m As Integer
Dim area As Range
Count = Range("K:K").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("K2:K" & Count).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,   
CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("Z2"), Unique:=True

Columns(26).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)


Count1 = Range("L:L").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("L2:L" & Count1).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,    
CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("Y2"), Unique:=True
Columns(25).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
Dim arrayv As String

Dim Text1 As String

Dim arrayv1 As String

last = Range("Z2").End(xlDown).Row
  
arrayv = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("Z2:Z" & last).Value)


last1 = Range("Y2").End(xlDown).Row
  
arrayv1 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("Y2:Y" & last1).Value)

Columns(26).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(25).EntireColumn.Delete

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim flag As Variant
flag = 1

A = 1
s = 2
For c = 1 To UBound(arrayv1)

For t = 1 To UBound(arrayv)

Sheets.Add().Name = "Sheet" & s
ActiveSheet.Move After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
j = 2
.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet" & s).Range("A" & 1)
flag = 1
For i = 2 To Count
     If .Cells(i, 11).Value = arrayv(t) Then
     If .Cells(i, 12).Value = arrayv1(c) Then
     Text = .Cells(i, 15).Value
              
     
     flag = 0

           .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet" & s).Range("A" & j)
           
        
           j = j + 1
           End If
        
     End If
  Next i

    If flag = 1 Then
    
    Sheets("Sheet" & s).Delete
    
    Else
    
   Text1 = Left(Text, 4)
```

Error line when column K has only one value

```
 arrayv = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("Z2:Z" & last).Value)
```

Error line when column L has only one value

```
arrayv1 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("Y2:Y" & last1).Value)
```

Comment: It looks like *last* and/or *last1* are referencing row 1,048,576. Trying to `.Transpose` Y2:Y1048576 exceeds the Transpose function limits (I think it is 65,536).

Comment: Change your arrays to variants not strings

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one value Y2 or Z2 downwards then using the [Range,End property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839539.aspx) with an [xlDirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820880.aspx) of `xlDown` is going to reference row  1,048,576. The [WorksheetFunction.Transpose method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196261.aspx) has a limit of  65,536. Anything exceeding this limit will result in,

> Run-time error '13':
> Type mismatch.

Change the direction of the last-row-seek to look up from the bottom with `xlUp`.

```
last = Range("Z" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
arrayv = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("Z2:Z" & last).Value)


last1 = Range("Y" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
arrayv1 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("Y2:Y" & last1).Value)
```

Comment: thanks for the info. I changed the code with x1Up and run. Still having same error but now the line is

        For c = 1 To UBound(arrayv1)

Comment: That would be because a single cell value is not an array and does not have a [UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) property. You could try changing both of them to look like `For LBound(Array(arrayv1)) to UBound(Array(arrayv1))` but that might just shift the problem further down again. Consider identifying single entries and running a separate process.

Comment: thanks again for the info. I have an idea to bypass this issue and use the original code..I will write a code to insert one row upfront which will have a combination AA - ZZ and write another code for deleting the tab named AA - ZZ at the end of the macro. This should work. I can write the code to insert the row but i donno the code to look for the tab AA-ZZ and delete it. Any luck on that ? Please note the tab can be 2) AA-ZZ , 3) AA-ZZ ...or any number ) AA-ZZ